# Can i override non virtual function in c++

Tags: c++, overriding

i wanna know can i override non virtual function in c++ because i found this problem when playing with c++
**override** keyword i have the code as follows

```
class A
{
public:
    void say()
    {
        cout << "From A\n";
    }
};
class B : public A {
public:
    void say()
        override
    {
        cout << "From B\n";
    }
};
```

but when i execute the code visual studio display the following error
**'B::say': method with override specifier 'override' did not override any base class methods**
but when i used virtual keyword in class A then error gone and code runs perfectly

Comment: That you can't do it is a pretty strong indicator that you can't, isn't it?. You might want to pick something from [the book list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: You've stumbled upon one of the most practical implications of the difference between *virtual* and *non-virtual* class members. Are you by any chance more familiar with Java? In the latter, all methods are virtual by default.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Should not Override Non-Virtual Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30679818/why-should-not-override-non-virtual-functions)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not override *say* in *B*

[from C++ override specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) :

> In a member function declaration or definition, override ensures that the function is virtual and is overriding a virtual function from a base class. The program is ill-formed (a compile-time error is generated) if this is not true.

Look at that example :

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
  public:
    void say()
    {
        std::cout << "From A\n";
    }
};

class B : public A {
  public:
    void say()
        //override
    {
        std::cout << "From B\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
  A a;
  B b;
  
  a.say();
  b.say();
  ((A &) b).say();
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ c.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
From A
From B
From A
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Putting *say* virtual in A (so implicitely in B) `((A &) b).say();` prints `From B` because that time there is overriding

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot.
"In a member function declaration or definition, override ensures that the function is virtual and is overriding a virtual function from a base class. The program is ill-formed (a compile-time error is generated) if this is not true."

Also see the answer  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39932616)

Comment: Thanks for your answer i just got confused by watching answers on various websites like
[programiz](https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/function-overriding#:~:text=If%20you%20create%20an%20object,is%20known%20as%20function%20overriding.) and [javatpoint](https://www.javatpoint.com/cpp-function-overriding) and many others.I am not understanding how they can say the examples they provided are the examples of overriding so i just put **override** keyword becuase i know its gonna say thats not overriding as it is developed to detect weather the function is being overritten or not

Answer (score 0):

`override` does not mean that the function you mark will magically override the base function. It's purpose is to tell the compiler "please check that I'm actually overriding a base class virtual function here and give me a nice compiler error if I screwed up, instead of doing something I did not intend".

If the base class function is `virtual` you don't *need* to say `override`, but you can do so to help yourself make fewer mistakes.

If the base class function is *not* `virtual` you cannot override it, `override` keyword or not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer i just got confused by watching answers on various websites like
[programiz](https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/function-overriding#:~:text=If%20you%20create%20an%20object,is%20known%20as%20function%20overriding.) and [javatpoint](https://www.javatpoint.com/cpp-function-overriding) and many others.I am not understanding how they can say the examples they provided are the examples of overriding so i just put **override** keyword becuase i know its gonna say thats not overriding as it is developed to detect weather the function is being overritten or not